# jOOQ + Liquibase + H2 in unit test results in "schema not found" exception

Tags: java, sql, h2, liquibase, jooq

i'm writing unit tests for some data access code. the key pieces in the setup consist of:

- `jOOQ` generated artifacts for CRUD operations
- `Liquibase` to handle schema evolutions

given as much, i'm trying to setup the tests as follows:

1. create a `java.sql.Connection` to initialize an H2 database with the appropriately named schema. (it's worth noting here that the connection is created with the following URL:
   `jdbc:h2:mem:[schema-name];MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`).
2. using the aforementioned connection, invoke `Liquibase` to run through a change log that creates all the objects in the database schema
3. using the aforementioned connection, create a `org.jooq.DSLContext` with which the data access components can be tested.

an abstract class encapsulates these three steps in a `@Before` annotated method, and test classes extend this abstract class to leverage the initialized `org.jooq.DSLContext` instance. something like this:

```java
abstract class DbTestBase {
    protected lateinit var dslContext: DSLContext

    private lateinit var connection: Connection

    open fun setUp() {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:foo;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1")

        // invoke Liquibase with this connection instance...

        dslContext = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.H2)
    }

    open fun tearDown() {
        dslContext.close()

        connection.close()
    }
}

class MyTest : DbTestBase() {
    private lateinit var repository: Repository

    @Before override fun setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        repository = Repository(dslContext)
    }

    @After override fun tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    @Test fun something() {
        repository.add(Bar())
    }
}
```

this results in the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "foo" not found; SQL statement:
insert into `foo`.`bar` (`id`) values (?) [90079-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSchema(Parser.java:688)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSchema(Parser.java:694)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5535)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5529)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1062)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:417)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:321)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:293)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:258)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:578)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:519)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1204)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288)
    at org.jooq.impl.ProviderEnabledConnection.prepareStatement(ProviderEnabledConnection.java:106)
    at org.jooq.impl.SettingsEnabledConnection.prepareStatement(SettingsEnabledConnection.java:70)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.prepare(AbstractQuery.java:410)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDMLQuery.prepare(AbstractDMLQuery.java:342)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:316)
    ... 25 more
```

i can see the `Liquibase` logging at the point where the schema is regenerated. and i've since changed the H2 URL to create file-based database, which i was able to inspect and verify that the schema does indeed exist.

i'd appreciate any help in spotting anything wrong in the approach.

Comment: Maybe add the `INIT=create schema if not exists foo` to your connection string like this: `"jdbc:h2:mem:foo;INIT=create schema if not exists foo\;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"`

Comment: hmmm but won't that just create an empty database/schema? i need to use the `Liquibase` generated version of the schema in order for the `jOOQ` generated code to work.

Comment: What *is* the "Liquibase" generated version of the schema?

Comment: @hsl You are right. Read your question again. Maybe a problem in jOOQ which I do not know anything about.

Comment: @LukasEder perhaps i phrased my earlier comment poorly. what i meant was that in this process, `Liquibase` re-creates the database/schema from a change log (which is a sort of manifest of all the objects in the schema). once that database/schema has been re-created, i want to use my `jOOQ` generated code to interact with it.

Comment: I see. And you're positive that you have correctly created the schema foo? (note that the `foo` in your JDBC connection URL is the database (= catalog) name, not the schema name)

Comment: i think this is where i might be going wrong. i use the terms "schema" and "database" interchangeably. do you think it's the case that i'm creating the database/catalog via the connection URL, and that i also need to create the schema in order for my `jOOQ` artifacts to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after much trial and error i was able to work through my issues by resolving two problems:

1. Lukas's comment differentiating "database" (or "catalog") vs "schema" pushed me in the right direction. though the terms seem to be used interchangeably in MySQL (my production database), they are not in H2. seems rather obvious in hindsight, but the remedy to this was to invoke a JDBC call to manually construct the schema and then set it as the default just before invoking Liquibase to reconstruct the schema, a la:

   ```
   ...
   connection = DriverManager.getConnection(...)

   connection.createStatement().executeUpdate("create schema $schemaName")

   connection.schema = schemaName.toUpperCase()

   // invoke Liquibase with this connection
   ...
   ```

despite opening a case-insensitive connection to H2, the `toUpperCase()` invocation still proved necessary. not sure why...

2. `jOOQ` quotes names for all schema objects so as to make them case-insensitive. however, as i've come to understand, quotes are used to *enforce* case-sensitivity in H2. the presence of the quotes in the generated queries were therefore causing a slew of errors due to objects that could not be found. the remedy for this was to supply a different `RenderNameStyle` to the query generator that would omit the quotes, a la:

   ```
   ...
   val settings = Settings().withRenderNameStyle(RenderNameStyle.AS_IS)

   val dslContext = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.H2, settings)
   ...
   ```

hope this can be of help to someone else down the line.

Comment: To address point 1, I have this JDBC URL `jdbc:h2:mem:aad_data;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS aas_data\\;SET SCHEMA aas_data`. Note the INIT part creating the schema and using it. Eventually I've removed the schema from the generated SQL (`Settings.withRenderSchema(false)`) in order to allow for different schema names. Point 2 is spot on!